# Crystal report: Calculate date given work week number and a year

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, formulas

Is there any formula to get the date of Sunday in Crystal report vb.net having a work week number and a year? For example I have

Work week # 46 and Year 2012..It should display the date of Sunday in the work week 46 in year 2012 (11,11,2012)

Comment: are you want count the sunday in a perticuler year?

Comment: No..I want to have a result of a date of sunday having a workweek number and a year..for example..the given is 4612..it should have 11/11/2012 because the date of sunday of workweek 46 in the year 2012 is 11/11/2012

Answer (score 0):

there is not any default functions to get that but i created a function myself to fix this issuse like this:

```
Public Function W_SUNDAY(ByVal TWEEK As Byte, ByVal TYEAR As Integer)
    Dim SRCDATE As Date = New Date(TYEAR, 1, 1) ' 1.1.2014 - BECAUSE BEGINING IS THE FIRST WEEK OF YEAR
    For I = 1 To 12
        For J = 1 To 31
            Dim CTDATE As Date
            Try ' TRAP ERRORS BECAUSE NOT ALL OF THE MONTHS HAS 31 DAYS :)
                CTDATE = New Date(TYEAR, I, J)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            If CTDATE.DayOfYear = 7 * (TWEEK - 1) Then
                SRCDATE = CTDATE
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    If SRCDATE.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
        For D = 1 To 6
            SRCDATE = DateAdd("d", 1, SRCDATE)
            If SRCDATE.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Return SRCDATE
End Function
```

let me know if this helped you :)
(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Hi thank you for this helpful code.but we have only a formula needed in crystal report since we are not using a form...because from the code you have given it was necessary needed to have a form..do you have any code for formula in C.R? thank you in advance

Comment: It's a pity that i have recently begun to learn C.R. so I'm sorry that i will not be able to help :(